# How to take only year from Date in string format?

Tags: java

I will get `Date` in string format like `11/01/2017`. From that string I want to take only the year. Like

```
String stringDate="11/01/2017";
```

the output I want is just "`2017`";

How to split that string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to split on forward slash and retain the third part:

```
String input = "11/01/2017";
String year = input.split("/")[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a String and will always be *dd/mm/yyyy*, then you can simply do:

```
dateString.substring(6)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as well.

```
String input="11/1/2017";
String year=input .substring(input .length()-4);
```